# ¿Qué significa "<>" en C?

Tags: c, operador

Vi la siguiente expresión en un código y no tengo idea qué significa:

```
if (fecha1.dia <> fecha2.dia)
```

Comment: Ese código jamás compilará. No existe ningún operador `<>` en C

Comment: No estoy seguro pero tiene la pinta de significar distinto de. Yo siempre utilizo != en su lugar. Por lo que <> y != podrían ser equivalentes

Comment: @YORS, puedes probarlo si no me crees. ¿Para qué van a existir dos operadores que hagan exactamente lo mismo?

Comment: @eferion Aunque tienes razon en el caso del C, perfectamente se podría tener dos operadores para lo mismo. Mira PHP, que tiene `!=` y `<>` con el mismo significado.

Comment: Mi hipótesis es que quien escribió ese código, si dice que es C, es que se ha liado con otro lenguaje, y que no ha probado a compilar ese código. PHP y Pascal usan `<>`  como comparador de desigualdad.

Comment: @abulafia puede ser. estuve con PHP hace ya más de 10 años. Si existen los dos operadores imagino que alguna diferencia habrá entre ellos, si no es, desde mi punto de vista, absurdo

Comment: En C es un error. Pero en otros lenguajes es el operador distinto. A mi me costó mucho usar el != Porque en TurboBASIC se utilizaba <>. En algunos lenguajes todavía se usa como "distinto de".

Comment: Es normal que haya varias formas de hacer la misma cosa:
Por ejemplo : i++; i=i+1;i+=1 son equivalentes. Quizas se base en otro leguaje. No lo sé. Pero de un for puedes hacer un while

Answer (score 2):

Significa **Error**. Este código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct fecha
{
    int dia;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct fecha fecha1;
    struct fecha fecha2;

    if (fecha1.dia <> fecha2.dia)
        printf("<>");

    return 0;
}
```

Genera el siguiente error de compilación:

> ```
> error: expected expression
>        if (fecha1.dia <> fecha2.dia)
>                        ^
> ```

El operador `<` (menor que) es un operador binario, esto significa que espera dos operandos, un operando a la izquierda del símbolo y otro a la derecha:

```
operando_izquierdo < operando_derecho
```

En lugar de una expresión que pudiera ser interpretada como un operando, se encuentra otro operador, generando el error `expected expression` que se traduce como `esperaba una expresión`.